# Как настроить регистрацию на asterisk 13 из мира?

Tags: asterisk

Как настроить регистрацию на asterisk 13 из мира? 
сделал вот так в pjsip.conf:
;===============TRANSPORT

[simpletrans]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=внутреннийIP/24
local_net=127.0.0.1/32
external_media_address=внешнийIP
external_signaling_address=внешнийIP

;===============ENDPOINT 6003

[6003]
type = endpoint
transport = simpletrans
context = test
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
aors = 6003
auth = auth6003
direct_media=no

[6003]
type = aor
contact = sip:6003@внешнийIP:5060
max_contacts = 100

[auth6003]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=blablabla
username=blablabla

По локальной сети регаюсь и звоню, а с внешнего зарегаться не могу.
Решил начать изучать астериск с 13. Говорят что он стабильней.

Comment: Как глобальная сеть приходит к астериску?

Comment: @gbg используеться NAT

Comment: Пробросы портов на шлюзе корректно настроены?

Comment: Оказалось, мой софтфон просто не пропускал в мир проксисервер))